# Mock DOM method jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, jestjs, mocking

I am have trouble trying to make a unit test for this function. The problem is it using a lib noUiSlider for a range slider and when the test get there , it does not recongnise noUiSlider.set. How do I correctly mock this
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

```
function popState(){ 
    if (rangeSlider) {
          $('.range-reset.' + name).removeClass('hidden');
          var element = self.isRangeElement(name).element;
          var unit = element.getAttribute('data-unit');
          //since noUiSlider accepts no unit,Remove unit from values
          unit = new RegExp(unit, 'g');
          value = value.replace(unit, '');
          value = value.split('-');
          ***element.noUiSlider.set(value);***
        }
}
```

I have tried this approach it did not work

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
const dom = new JSDOM();
dom.noUiSlider = {
  set: jest.fn() 
} ;
global.window = dom.window;
```

And I have tried this as well none work

```
    Object.defineProperty(window.document, 'noUiSlider', {
     set: jest.fn(),
   });
```

Unit test case

```
     test('should set range state', () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = `<div id="twobuttons-range_0" class="twobuttons-range" data-technicalname="motor" data-unit="mm" data-min="100" data-max="500" data-start="[30,50]"></div>`;
   Object.defineProperty(window.document, 'noUiSlider', {
     set: jest.fn(),
   });
    popState();
    expect($('#twobuttons-range_0').length).toBe(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this and it works:

Inside myComponent.tsx:

```
import noUiSlider from "nouislider";
....
globalSlider: noUiSlider.noUiSlider;
```

Inside myComponent.spec.tsx:

```
component = new myComponent();
...
it("Set value for slider", () => {
    component.globalSlider = {
      options: undefined, target: undefined, destroy(): void {
      }, get(): string | string[] {
        return undefined;
      }, off(): void {
      }, on(): void {
      }, reset(): void {
      }, updateOptions(): void {
      }, set: jest.fn() };

    component.setSliderValue("3");
  });
```